# How to show hidden files whose names match a pattern with ls?

Tags: bash

Consider a directory which contains the following stuff. `abc-dir1` is a directory. Others are files.

```
abc-dir1
abc-file1
.abc-file2
def-file1
```

`ls -d *abc*` produces list 1:

```
abc-dir1  
abc-file1
```

I want to show all directories and files (including hidden directories and files) whose names match `*abc*`. list 2 is what I want:

```
abc-dir1  
abc-file1
.abc-file2
```

But `ls -a -d *abc*` still produces list 1. So it seems that the existence of `*abc*` overrides the effect of `-a` option. Is there a way to show list 2 with [ls](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ls.1.html)?

Comment: Try adding a pattern that matches the hidden file as well: `ls -d *abc* .*abc*`, or using extended globbing: `ls -d ?(.)*abc*`

Comment: `ls -a | grep abc` maybe?

Comment: You could also use: "find . -maxdepth 1 -name '\*abc\*'"

Answer (score 5):

hidden files starts with point, regular files don't, so:

```
ls -d {.,}*abc*
```

Comment: Note that this results in the shell having to expand two separate patterns, `.*abc*` and `*abc*`, but that should be of little or no practical concern.

Comment: @tso, I don't want to show content inside directory `abc-dir1`. So `ls -d {.,}*abc*` is what I want. And `ls -d *abc* .*abc*` produces the same result as `ls -d {.,}*abc*`.

Comment: ok, i've edited. Yep, as @chepner said {.,}*abc* shell expand this in two separate patterns, .*abc* and \*abc\*

Answer (score 5):

Turn on the `dotglob` option.

```
$ shopt -s dotglob
$ printf '%s\n' *abc*
abc-dir1  
abc-file1
.abc-file2
```

If you really want to show file that "*start*" with `abc` (with or without an initial `.`), use an extended pattern instead.

```
$ shopt -s extglob
$ printf '%s\n' ?(.)abc*
```

I've used `printf` in place of `ls`. Unless you are using one or more options with `ls` to sort, show additional metadata, etc, there's no need to run an external program just to display file names.

Comment: With `shopt -s extglob`, `ls -d ?(.)abc*` produces what I want. And with `shopt -s dotglob`, `ls -d *abc*` produces what I want.

Answer (score 0):

Combination of ls -al and grep will do it..

```
mebada@mebada-T430:~$ ls -al | grep zil
drwx------   4 mebada mebada       4096 Jan 18 01:14 .mozilla
```